# Decoding muli-length opcodes (SPU ISA)

Tags: cpu-architecture, dump, opcode, hexdump, spu

I have produced a dump of 32-bit instructions in hex from an assembler I implemented. A subset of the instruction dump is show below:

[image]

The opcodes for the instructions are of lengths 4, 7, 8, 9, and 11. They are always the first bits in the instruction. I'm having trouble understanding how I would decode the instructions if the opcodes are of different lengths?

For example: When I read a single instruction, how would I know how many bits I should read for the opcode?

Here is an image of the instruction formats:
[image: format]

Thank you

Comment: How can we know? I assume there is a logic in the opcodes, otherwise no processor can decode them. Maybe if he first 3 bits are 111, the length is 7 and so on. But with the information that you give, it is impossible to give you any advice.

Comment: The rest of the fields in the instructions are all operands or immediate's. There is no additional information in the instruction other than the opcode.
I've added a picture of the instruction formats.

Comment: You must look at the instruction description. For instance, with a rapid scan of the sony document, I noticed that all 10 bits opcode instruction start with 001. There is probably a similar logic for other instructions.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to find a pattern like that. Since the smallest opcode is 4 bits, there must be a pattern within the first 4 bits of each instruction; but there isn't (that I can see). Some instructions (of different opcode lengths) have the same first 4 bits.

Comment: There **is** a logic. Otherwise the processor is unable decode instructions. Try to find the minimum pattern length that can determine pattern size and use a look up table.

Comment: I figured it out, I posted the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
I read the maximum number of opcode bits (11) for all instructions, and ignore the bits that don't make sense (i.e the bits that wouldn't result in a possible opcode).